# AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application i use 2 asyncTasks simultanously to read 2seperate xmls into strings.
However, sometimes when i run application i only get white screen then it goes back to desktop after a little while. In main i'm doing do{}while(!read1 || !read2) to wait for the xmls to get read. Then i process the strings further.

Here is my code for asyncTask, the other one is very similar.

```
private class Read1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... read) {
            String text="";
            try {

                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(sdcard,read[0]);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-2"),8192);
                    String line;   
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                text+=line;

                                } br.close();}
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            text1=text;
            read1=true;
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Actually. Most of the times i get this white screen is when i close the app and then run it again in a short time. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling the task?

Comment: "goes back to desktop" sounds like it's crashing.  Do you see a crash in the `logcat` output?

Comment: The only thing that seems suspicious is:

04-11 22:58:26.900: E/dalvikvm(17425): threadid=2: stuck on threadid=1, giving up
04-11 22:58:26.900: D/dalvikvm(17425): threadid=2: sending two SIGSTKFLTs to threadid=1 (tid=17425) to cause debuggerd dump
04-11 22:58:26.900: A/libc(17425): Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x00004411 (code=-6), thread 17425 (project.listxml)

Comment: I am calling the task like this:

new Read1().execute("nbp.xml");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not wait in main but process strings further in onPostExecute().

Comment: Well, later i would have to parse this string to get some info from xmls and put them into the list view. Do you mean that i should do all of this in onPostExecute()?

Comment: Yes you should do that in the onPostExecute() of the last finishing task. And do away with the do-while in main.